# PayPal - Reason ui_unhandled_api_error

Tags: paypal

Our customers are getting the ***Sorry — your last action could not be completed*** message.

And the URL is showing ***fallback?product=ec&fallback=1&reason=ui_unhandled_api_error***

1. Customer sees the amount they need to pay.
2. Customer wants to log in.
3. This error is showing.

I can't find anything about this ***ui_unhandled_api_error*** issue.

Does anyone know what this means and how to resolve it?

Thanks.